# How to use a variable from a function declared above the return function?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to retrieve the users saved theme from Async storage, then I want to use a variable to set the pages theme to whatever they've chosen. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKbKh.png)

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/BD7620/app-dev?file=/App.js

Comment: Please don't upload screenshot of code snippet and share the code instead.[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.